# How do I run a macro on change to a field, but not on original entry of that field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a Projects database which includes a form with fields for staff to complete on startup of a project.

The first field, 'ClientCode' is a compulsory dropdown list (Combobox) of Clients.

To avoid accidental changes to this field, I added 'On Change' code to display a warning message:

```
Private Sub ComboClientCode_Change()
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the client?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

It works, however I don't want it to run when someone starts a new record i.e. selects the client for the first time.

How do I make this message only show if it is a change to the original entry?

I tried moving it to 'AfterUpdate' but it does the same thing.

Comment: Why don't you just check if there is a value selected already? As in, I assume your default state is a blank choice or something like "Select Client Code". All you need to do is run a check to ensure that the defaults aren't there and then run the code.

Comment: Thanks Dean De Villiers, that sounds like what I want to do.  The default state is blank.  So I had a crack at the code but have failed, getting the message "Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object".  I clearly don't know what i'm doing.  Can you tell me what i've done wrong?

If Me.ComboClientCode <> "" Then MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the client?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo
       DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
            Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

Answer (score 0):

You could change one of the "irrelevant" properties of the combobox the first time it gets changed.

```
Private Sub ComboClientCode_Change()
    If ComboClientCode.ColumnHeads = False Then
        ComboClientCode.ColumnHeads = True
    Else
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the client?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
            Debug.Print "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Should work for this type:

[image: Type]

Listed properties of above selected type:

[image: Properties]

You can run this to make the existing one change if it has a value:

```
Sub Switch()
    If ComboClientCode.Value <> "" Then
        ComboClientCode.ColumnHeads = True
    Else
        ComboClientCode.ColumnHeads = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks AsUsual, i tried this and it didn't work. It probably didn't help that there just wasn't a "Placement" property, i don't know why.  I understand your logic and I like it but I realised when I was doing it that the Placement (or which ever irrelevant property I used) won't have changed for the existing projects where clients have already been selected.

Comment: Well yeah, use another property then and run a macro on the existing ones so that all of the comboboxes with values matches the property that initializes the code. If your intention is to open each file and paste the code then you can paste two and run one of them

Comment: Thanks again AsUsual.  It just didn't seem to work, the ColumnHeads seem to remain at false.  I'm on a bit of a deadline so i've decided to put this aside for the time being and i can come back to it later. You have been a great help though esp with getting me to think outside the box.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I haven't tested any of the code below so let me know if it works for you. I propose 2 different solutions, and depending on if the logic works, the solution will work.

**Solution 1:**

Using the change event, you check the combobox value, and if it is blank then run the code. My concern with this is that when the event handler fires there will **only** be a value in there because the user would have changed the value to call the event handler. Nonetheless, the code would look like something below.

```vb
Private Sub ComboClientCode_Change()

    If Me.ComboClientCode.Value <> "" Then
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the client?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
           DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
                Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Solution 2:**

With this solution the logic seems a bit more sound than the above method. What will happen is you will set the default value of the combobox using the `UserForm_Initialize()` event handler. Then, when your user selects from the dropdown list it will set the value to that variable, and will prevent the unnecessary pop up. See below code. Your userform module should look like the below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim sClientCode As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    sClientCode = Me.ComboClientCode.Value

End Sub

Private Sub ComboClientCode_Change()

    If sClientCode <> "" Then
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the client?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
           'set the value now
           sClientCode = Me.ComboClientCode.Value
           DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
                Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dean, I've tried both solutions. The first looked perfect, but it didn't work - no message, just like it wasn't there.  The second solution didn't work either, but when i put the code in it split into three sub sections (not sure of terminology). The first one being your first two lines of code (Option Explicit; Dim sClientCode As String) which actually adding its self to the previous sub.